# CreateFile function executed without errors but doesn't create any files

Tags: c++, file-io, createfile

I have such implementation in my method

```cpp
std::string name2 = "D:\\Buffer\\Temp\\t_libpng" + std::to_string(i) + ".png";
```

```cpp
bool _write_png_file_cv2_(char const *filename,
    int width, 
    int height,
    int widthStep,
    png_byte color_type, 
    png_byte bit_depth, 
    png_bytep *row_pointers)
{
    // ...

    hFile = CreateFile((LPCWSTR)filename,      // Open Two.txt.
                       GENERIC_WRITE,          // Open for writing
                       0,                      // Do not share
                       NULL,                   // No security
                       OPEN_ALWAYS,            // Open or create
                       FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,  // Normal file
                       NULL);                  // No template file

    if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        printf("ERROR:: Could not open file");
        CloseHandle(hFile);            // Close the first file.
        return false;
    }

    DWORD dwBytesWritten;

    //fclose(fp);
    //writeSamsungToDisk(png->buffer,png->idx);

    BOOL result = WriteFile(
        hFile, 
        png->buffer,
        png->idx, 
        &dwBytesWritten,
        NULL);

    CloseHandle(hFile);

    // ...
}
```

Filename in this case is `D:\\Buffer\\Temp\\t_libpng0.png` and size of buff is 8977.

1. If I stop debug on this line `if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)` I see that I don't get any errors, as for me it is means that I can go to destination `D:\\Buffer\\Temp` and find there my file, but there is nothing.
2. I thought maybe it is just a handle (but `OPEN_ALWAYS` should create a file).
3. I moved further to line `CloseHandle(hFile)` and checked the variable `dwBytesWritten` and I see that number of written bytes is 8977, exactly the same.
4. So, I came up to the end of the method without any error but still any I don't see any files within my destination.

What is the problem here?

Comment: Are there actually double backslashes in the filename?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz yes, edited my question

Comment: Why are you doing this cast - `(LPCWSTR)filename`? Do you understand what it is doing? `filename` is `const char *`.

Comment: @StaceyGirl maybe not exactly understand. Yes, it is char *.  But reason is because without this case I get this error `argument of type const char * is incompatible with parameter of type lpcwstr`

Comment: Are you converting the file name to a wide char string since you cast to a wide char pointer? Or just giving it as a regular char pointer? If you’re giving non-wide name to a wide char expecting function it may do weird things. Unless your cast is wrong and you’re using the A versions of the functions.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen but without this cast I get such error `argument of type const char * is incompatible with parameter of type lpcwstr`

Comment: Call `CreateFileA` with the const char* (no cast).

Comment: But are you converting it to wide char string or not? You can’t just cast it and assume it to work. It requires a wide char string.

Comment: @jwdonahue yes, right, thanks! You can public as an answer I'll accept it

Comment: I am sure this problem has duplicates, but I am too lazy to go and find them at the moment, so writing up an answer would definitely be a waste of time.

Comment: The compiler doesn't generate errors just for the fun of it.  You should pay attention and understand what it's trying to tell you.  A pointer to a `char` is not compatible with a pointer to a `wchar_t`.

Comment: A cast tells the compiler to look at data a different way, it doesn't (usually) actually change anything. If you lie to the compiler and tell it a variable has the wrong "shape" just to eliminate a compiler error, it will get its revenge at runtime.

Comment: Also, you've probably created some strangely named files that you did not recognize when you were testing your code.

Comment: @jwdonahue yes, sure, no problem. Thanks one more

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### You have an invalid type-cast in your code.

`CreateFile()` is a preprocessor macro that maps to either `CreateFileW()` (which takes `wchar_t*`) or `CreateFileA()` (which takes `char*`) depending on whether `UNICODE` is defined.  Clearly `UNICODE` is defined in your project, which is why `CreateFile()` expects `wchar_t*`.

```
// winbase.h

WINBASEAPI
__out
HANDLE
WINAPI
CreateFileA(
    __in     LPCSTR lpFileName,
    __in     DWORD dwDesiredAccess,
    __in     DWORD dwShareMode,
    __in_opt LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpSecurityAttributes,
    __in     DWORD dwCreationDisposition,
    __in     DWORD dwFlagsAndAttributes,
    __in_opt HANDLE hTemplateFile
    );
WINBASEAPI
__out
HANDLE
WINAPI
CreateFileW(
    __in     LPCWSTR lpFileName,
    __in     DWORD dwDesiredAccess,
    __in     DWORD dwShareMode,
    __in_opt LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpSecurityAttributes,
    __in     DWORD dwCreationDisposition,
    __in     DWORD dwFlagsAndAttributes,
    __in_opt HANDLE hTemplateFile
    );
#ifdef UNICODE
#define CreateFile  CreateFileW
#else
#define CreateFile  CreateFileA
#endif // !UNICODE
```

You are type-casting your `filename` parameter from `char*` to `wchar_t*`.  Casting a `char*` pointer to `wchar_t*` will not work in this case, as evident by the fact that the compiler complains when you remove the type-cast.  All the type-cast does is lie to the compiler, telling it that the pointer is pointing at `wchar_t` data, when in reality it is actually pointing at `char` data instead.

As such, when you have a `char*` pointer to a `char` string `"D:\\Buffer\\Temp\\t_libpng0.png"`, and you pass that pointer type-casted to `CreateFileW()`, the function thinks you are passing it a double-byte `wchar_t` string `"㩄䉜晵敦屲敔灭瑜江扩湰で瀮杮"` instead:

[image]

Notice the *bytes* don't change, just the *interpretation* of them.  This kind of mismatch is commonly referred to as ["mojibake"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake).

`"㩄䉜晵敦屲敔灭瑜江扩湰で瀮杮"` is a *perfectly valid file name* for `CreteFileW()`, but it has no directory specified, so `CreateFileW()` will treat the string as a *relative path* and create that file in the calling process's *current working directory*.  That is why your code is not failing, but the file is not where you are expecting, or named what you are expecting.

So, to use the `CreateFile()` macro properly in this situation, you would have to actually *convert* your `char` data to `wchar_t` data using `MultiByteToWideChar()` (or equivalent), eg:

```cpp
#ifdef UNICODE

int len = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, filename, -1, NULL, 0);
wchar_t *w_filename = new wchar_t[len];
MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, filename, -1, w_filename, len);
hFile = CreateFile(w_filename, ...);
// better:
// hFile = CreateFileW(w_filename, ...);
delete[] w_filename;

#else

hFile = CreateFile(filename, ...);
// better:
// hFile = CreateFileA(filename, ...);

#endif
```

Or, change your `filename` parameter from `char*` to `wchar_t*` to begin with, and then update the caller to use `std::wstring` instead of `std::string`, eg:

```cpp
std::wstring name2 = L"D:\\Buffer\\Temp\\t_libpng" + std::to_wstring(i) + L".png";
_write_png_file_cv2_(name2.c_str(), ...);
```

```cpp
bool _write_png_file_cv2_(wchar_t const *filename, ...)
{
    // ...

    hFile = CreateFile(filename, ...);
    // better:
    // hFile = CreateFileW(filename, ...);

    // ...
}
```

Otherwise, if you want to continue using `std::string`/`char*` then you can just call `CreateFileA()` directly instead, and let it handle the conversion internally for you:

```
hFile = CreateFileA(filename, ...);
```

A good rule of thumb - whenever you are NOT using the `TCHAR` type in your code, you should stay away from using any `TCHAR`-based function macros.  Use functions that are specific to the actual data type(s) you are using.  For instance, in this situation, by calling `CreateFileA()` for `char*` and `CreateFileW()` for `wchar_t*`, not `CreateFile()` at all.

Comment: I really hate the way Microsoft overloads the API functions using macros.  Sure it made life a tiny bit easier for those that were translating their programs from code pages to Unicode, but the effects linger forever and are annoying.

Comment: @MarkRansom True. And that is largely caused by the Win32 API being a C-based API, not a C++-based API. C does not support function overloading, which is why they used preprocessor macros instead. What I wish MS would do is update the API headers such that when compiling for C++ then proper C++ wrappers are used (via overloads or templates) and eliminate the old `#define` macros, and when compiling for C then resort to the old `#define` macros.